# How do I obtain all the row names in a Cassandra table, efficiently?

Tags: cassandra, time-series, cassandra-2.0

I have a straightforward schema in Cassandra where I am storing a large amount of financial markets time series as per Pattern 1 in the recommendation [here](https://academy.datastax.com/demos/getting-started-time-series-data-modeling) ie:
[image]
 There are about 2000 tickers, each in their own row, and there are between 100k and 1m time series data points ("columns") for each of these. How do I efficiently get the ticker names (ie the 2000 ticker names? In the above analogy, the blue "WeatherStationID" cells?). The only difference from the above is that I have the rows ordered by time DESC so my actual table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ts.mindesc (
    ticker text,
    time timestamp,
    close float,
    high float,
    low float,
    numevents int,
    open float,
    source text,
    value float,
    PRIMARY KEY (ticker, time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time DESC)
```

Do I have to select * from the whole table above a certain timestamp value and parse this? The problem with that is that not all tickers have recent data so I might have to go quite far back in terms of time to capture them all, in which case for tickers with lots of recent data I could be getting through large amounts of redundant information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you should be able to query the partition keys very quickly by using `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ticker FROM ts.mindesc;
```

While 100k rows in CQL probably wouldn't perform well with an unbound WHERE, 2000 partition keys *shouldn't* be a problem.